# Attach() resets servo's angle

Tags: servo, pwm

I'm working on code that will control micro servo. I use generic servo and built-in library for controling servo. Microcontroller is generic STM32.
Controlling servo Works as expected. But I don't want next behavior - `attach()` function sets servo to 180°(maybe 0°, not sure).
In my project I want next:

- Servo stays at angle before going off/reboot
- Servo goes to 90° after turning on/reboot

I googled about this problem and tried with `write(90);` before `attach()` in `setup()` function. Servo goes to 90° but after like 50ms `attach()` stops `write(90)` function and it goes back to 180°. So this didn't solve my problem.
Next I've open `Servo.cpp` and found that `attach()` function contains next code:

```
    bool Servo::attach(uint8 pin,
                   uint16 minPW,
                   uint16 maxPW,
                   int16 minAngle,
                   int16 maxAngle) {
    timer_dev *tdev = PIN_MAP[pin].timer_device;

    if (tdev == NULL) {
        // don't reset any fields or ASSERT(0), to keep driving any
        // previously attach()ed servo.
        return false;
    }

    if (this->attached()) {
        this->detach();
    }

    this->pin = pin;
    this->minPW = minPW;
    this->maxPW = maxPW;
    this->minAngle = minAngle;
    this->maxAngle = maxAngle;

    pinMode(pin, PWM);

    timer_pause(tdev);
    timer_set_prescaler(tdev, SERVO_PRESCALER - 1); // prescaler is 1-based
    timer_set_reload(tdev, SERVO_OVERFLOW);
    timer_generate_update(tdev);
    timer_resume(tdev);

    return true;
}
```

What should I do to fix this problem? Servo will adjust angle of PCB which holds LEDs. PCB will be in case and angle of 90° is default angle. 0°/180° will either destory servo or brake case/PCB/something else.

Comment: If there are limits to the angles it can travel, I think you need to look at `minAngle` and `maxAngle`

Comment: You showed us the code from the core for the Servo library.  That code is KNOWN to work.  It works for everyone else.  Most likely the mistake is in the code that you wrote that you haven't shown us.  Please post the code you are having trouble with if you really want help.  It is impossible to help you fix code that I can't see.

Comment: @Delta_G Sorry for delayed answer. `HLServo.attach(PA8)` is in `setup()` function. Immediately after reboot servo goes to "neutral" angle. So problem lays in servo lib I guess. I'll try with min and max angle parameters.

Comment: You still aren't showing the code that you are having problems with.  It's like showing up at the mechanic to ask what's wrong with your car and not bringing the car with you.  Or asking the doctor to tell you what's wrong with your friend that you didn't bring with you.  It is impossible to diagnose what we can't see.  If you can't post the code that you have that you say isn't working then there isn't anything anyone can really do to help you.  Go edit your post and remove the Servo.cpp code.  We all have that code already.  And instead paste in the code that you have that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using the `attach();` method by programming without the servo library.

```
  for(x=0; x<150; x=x+1)
  {
    digitalWrite(Servomotor, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(2350); //Change the delay here to change the angle it goes to
    digitalWrite(Servomotor, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(18550);
  }
```

This is an example code for how it worked for me. It sends a pulse to the servo which makes it turn a bit until it reaches a "barrier".